# In R, how to apply a function on each dataframe row that uses a column value?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, nlp

Let's say I have a dataframe

Author |        Lyrics            |

Name1     Text (characters)

Name2     Text (characters)

I want to create another column through applying a function that for each row takes the Text from the Text column, separates by whitespaces, then iterates over each token to see if it is within another vector I made (so I can work out the percentage of tokens within the text that are within that other vector).

The function as I have written so far is below

```
ReturnPercentPosWord = function(textLyrics){
```

`WhitespaceSplitText = strsplit(textLyrics, " ")`

`LengthSplitText = length(WhitespaceSplitText)`

`CountInPosList = 0`

`for (i in WhitespaceSplitText) {`

```
if (i %in% PositiveWords$word) {
  CountInPosList = CountInPosList+1
}
```

`}`

```
 if (CountInPosList == 0) {
return(0)
```

`}`

```
PercentInPos = (CountInPosList/LengthSplitText)*100
```

`return(PercentInPos)}`

I want to apply this function to each row now.
I have tried

```
TestPOSwordsDF$PercentPositiveWords = ReturnPercentPosWord(TestPOSwordsDF$Lyrics)
```

and

```
TestPOSwordsDF$PercentPositiveWords = apply(TestPOSwordsDF[, c('Lyrics'),drop=F], 1, ReturnPercentPosWord)
```

But I get a message saying 
`the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

I would really appreciate any help with this. Thank you!

Comment: If you can provide a small amount of example data it would help. The error may be about the (i in WhitespaceSplitText) is the i here a list or vector? Because then (i %in% PositiveWords$word) will return that warning.

Comment: The dataframe I have looks something like this (sorry I'm not sure how to properly display this) \n Author     Lyrics \n                                                                                  WuTang  Shaolin shadowboxing, and the Wu-Tang sword style  \n                                                                                          WuTang  If what you say is true, the Shaolin and the Wu-Tang \n

Comment: So, WhitespaceSplitText is a list of tokens. So i will be individual words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this :

```
TestPOSwordsDF$PercentPositiveWords <- sapply(
                   strsplit(TestPOSwordsDF$Lyrics, " "), function(x) 
                   mean(x %in% PositiveWords$word) * 100)
```

Here we split `Lyrics` on space, get the ratio of words which are present in `PositiveWords$word`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Ronak. I am a bit confused as to why mean was used here. Can you explain this please? I would really appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: @BeginnerByron It is shortcut to get proportion here. `x %in% PositiveWords$word` returns logical values i.e `TRUE`/`FALSE`. Using `mean` we get ratio of values directly instead of doing `sum(x %in% PositiveWords$word)/length(x)`.

Comment: @BeginnerByron This is because boolean algebra equates TRUE, FALSE to 1, 0 respectively and so the mean equates to the proportion of matches. Eloquent answer as usual by the way Ronak!

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to reply!